# to display data depending on option choosen from dropdown

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I am a begginer in **programming**, I have `php` code and I want to display some data from `mysql` database depending on the option `selected from the dropdown` menu and here is the select menu:

```
  <p><select name="category"class="form-control1"  required="required">
          <option value="">--report category--</option>
          <option value="rbNumber"  >RB report & range of date</option>
          <option value="policeStationID" >Police station report & range of date</option>
          <option value="zone"  >zone report & range of date</option>
          <option value="region" >region report & range of date</option>

     </select> 
    &nbsp&nbsp
 <input type="date" name="date1" required="required">&nbsp&nbsp
 <input type="date" name="date2" required="required">&nbsp&nbsp
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search Report"></p></form></h2>
```

I want,  when I select `rb` report option then the query to be executed and select the corresponding data and display it.

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. 
We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. 
You are expected to try to write the code yourself.
Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can't be done in pure php. What you need is to use AJAX, here is example thread answering similar case:
[Fire AJAX when value selected from dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44414224/fire-ajax-when-value-selected-from-dropdown)